# How to use the tor browser as web driver selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am getting this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

This is my code:

```
String torPath = "C:\\Users\\camil\\Desktop\\Tor Browser\\Browser\\firefox.exe";
String profilePath = "C:/Users/camil/Desktop/Tor Browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default";
File torProfileDir = new File(profilePath);
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File(torPath));
FirefoxProfile torProfile = new FirefoxProfile(torProfileDir);

torProfile.setPreference("webdriver.load.strategy", "unstable");
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.setBinary(binary);
firefoxOptions.setProfile(torProfile);
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Beyond that: have you tried dong that; setting the path as **system property**?

Answer (score 0):

Successful launch Tor with existing browser profile:

```
package navi;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;

public class Tor_browser_test {
    private static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();         
        FirefoxProfile selenium_profile = allProfiles.getProfile("selenium_profile");
        options.setProfile(selenium_profile);
        options.setBinary("C:\\Users\\pburgr\\Desktop\\Tor browser\\Browser\\firefox.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\pburgr\\Desktop\\geckodriver-v0.20.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();}
    @Before
    public void setUp() {}
    @After
    public void tearDown() {}
    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {driver.quit();}
    @Test
    public void tor_browser_test() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: now I have another problem in the ProfilesIni class constructor profiles is created in null and without that part of the tor code it tells me that it has a problem with proxy

Comment: unfortunetly I didn't pass the proxy too. Why do you want use Tor?

Comment: I want to create a program that automatically creates Instagram accounts. That's why I wanted to take advantage of the anonymity of tor

Comment: This approach isn't  appropriate, using sandbox you don't need to be an anonym, see https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/.

Comment: Thanks for that information but I also wanted to expand to the rest of the social networks which I think would be the best way to do this anonymously

thanks for helping

Comment: @CamiloRomero That's not the way to do it. Most tor endpoints get blocked, as the advanced social media websites have some pretty good internal "politics" on endpoints.
What's the tor version you're using @pburgr?

Comment: @Jack Doe currently none, already deleted. But my try was with last stable release.

Comment: just like the friend I'm using the latest version